# How to show save and control button in Sharepoint forms without having users to scroll down to bottom

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, custom-list, list-form

In order to see "save" and "close" buttons in Sharepoint forms (edit, display or view  mode),  we  have to scroll down to the bottom.

How can I make all the controls visible at the same time without requiring to scroll ? I have used FormWebpart to set the height of the webpart, but there I can only hardcode (i.e height = 200px), I cannot set the percentage.

Problem:

[image]

Requirement:

[image]

Any Suggestions??

Comment: There are these big fat buttons in the ribbon. One is called Save, one is called Cancel. They are there to be clicked. They are always visible at the top. Why not use these?

Comment: Yes, But I found form interface very annoying, as half of the textbox is hidden and you have scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the aspx page in SPD, hide the existing form and then add a new custom form. It will have buttons at the top and the bottom. Don't manipulate the height. SharePoint will adjust the height as required and will only resort to scroll bars if the form does not fit on the screen.